# calling object members in c# foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have lot of tab pages in my program and I want to add or remove these pages. I'm using the following statement to do it.

```
if(this.myControlForm.TabPages.Contains(tabPage1))
{
    this.myControlForm.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1));
}
if(this.myControlForm.TabPages.Contains(tabPage2))
{
    this.myControlForm.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2));
}
[...] //similar code for other tabPages
```

but it makes too much code when I have a lot of tabpages to add or remove so I want to add them in an array and make a foreach loop but I got an error

my code is :

```
object[] listToRemove = {tabPage1, tabPage2,tabPage3, ... tabPage20};

foreach ( object itr in listToRemove)
{
    if(this.myControlForm.TabPages.Contains(itr))
    {
        this.myControlForm.TabPages.Remove(itr));
    }
}
```

Why is this happening, can anyone please help?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Change your `listToRemove` to be explicitly typed, i.e. from array of objects to the array of `TabPage`.

Same story with `itr` variable in loop.

`Contains` and `Remove` methods expects argument to be of type `TabPage`, not `object` - that's why you're getting errors.

```
TabPage[] listToRemove = {tabPage1, tabPage2,tabPage3, ... tabPage20};

foreach (TabPage itr in listToRemove)
{
  if(this.myControlForm.TabPages.Contains(itr))
      this.myControlForm.TabPages.Remove(itr);
}
```

Comment: I did try this too, and I get the following errors :
1- for Tabpage: tabPage is an ambigious reference between forms,
2- Best overload method...

Comment: Error 865 The best overloaded method match for 'MicroFour.StrataFrame.UI.Windows.Forms.TabPageCollection.Contains(MicroFour.StrataFrame.UI.Windows.Forms.TabPage)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user3456351 It will be much more easy to answer your question if you will provide complete errors text, not stripped to the first few words. Concerning the first error - it looks like you have some assembly except `System.Windows.Forms` referenced that includes definition for `TabPage`